# Apostol Calculus Volume 1: Theorem 1.2 proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm new to rigorous mathematics and have difficulty understanding the proof for theorem 1.2 (possibility of subtraction) in Apostol's Calculus Volume 1. Here's the theorem and it's proof:

Theorem 1.2. POSSIBILITY OF SUBTRACTION. Given $a$ and $b$, there is exactly one $x$ such that $a+x=b$. This $x$ is denoted by $b−a$. In particular, $0−a$ is written simply $−a$ and is called the negative of $a$.

*Proof of* 1.2. Given $a$ and $b$, choose $y$ so that $a+y=0$ and let **$x=y+b$**. Then, $a+x=a+(y+b)=(a+y)+b=0+b=b.$ Therefore there is at least one $x$ such that $a+x=b$. But by (another theorem) there is at most one such $x.$ Hence, there is exactly one.

In Apostol's argument, he constructs $x$ in a way, so that $x = y + b$. How can he assume that such a $b$ exists? To my naive mind, it seems like he's assuming the property that he needs to prove. Can somebody please explain this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The $a$ and the $b$ are given ("Given $a$ and $b$") in the statement of the theorem. The existence of $b$ doesn't need to be proven. The elements which existence need to be proven are $y$, and $y+b$, but very likely that has either been proven before, or are axioms. I don't know the context in which this theorem is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in the theorem, nor in its proof was there a need for an assumption that $b$ exists. As you can see both start with the sentence *"Given $a$ and $b$"*. So something that is given obviously exists. In the next part of the proof $y$ is chosen in such a way that it satisfies a condtion for already existent $a$ and then $x$ is constructed from already known $y$ and $b$.

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious lol. Thank you for taking the time to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement of the Theorem, $a$ and $b$ are given, so when you say "How can he assume that such a $b$ exists", I think you mean to ask how he can assume that such a $y$ exists?

If that is correct, then the existence of $y$ comes from one of the axioms, namely that additive inverses (or "negatives") exist. Recall that Axiom 4 (at least in the edition of Apostol that I have) requires that there is an additive identity $0$ with the property that $a+0=a$ for all $a$, and then Axiom 5 (existence of negatives) requires that, for each $a$, there is an element $x$ such that $a+x=0$. Apostol is applying Axiom 5 to obtain a $y$ with $a+y=0$, and then claiming that $x=y+b$ is a solution to the equation $a+x=b$.